# Does every new version / update of an Android Play Store App need to be reviewed?

Tags: android, flutter, version

I have set up and uploaded an app to the closed testing track in the Play Store Console, where it was reviewed for three days and approved.

Now, I just wanted to run a small update/patch for the app and uploaded a new app bundle for this. This new version is now again in review by in the Console.

Will this always be the case? Are these reviews of updates maybe faster than for the initial version?

Comment: Yes, because a series of items have already been checked by Google Play, the time for checking and confirming the new version is earlier.

Comment: The review process for app updates on the Google Play Store is typically faster than the initial review for a new app. The exact duration can vary based on factors such as the complexity of the update, changes made, and current review queue.

Comment: Yes, every app bundle is reviwed. If you update the patch number on app bundle (ie c part  of vA.b.c ) review will typically be faster than Initial or minor/Major number review.
Do follow the versioning convention.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to sum up my own experience here: As alright indicated by the helpful comments above, all further updates/releases within the closed testing track need to be reviewed and approved as well by Google Console.

However, my updates were mostly approved within one hour or two, much faster than the initial release in the closed testing track.